# How can I get the subscription back from a Recurly Purchase?

Tags: php, recurly

I am building a custom checkout with the [Recurly PHP Client](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-php). Since we use our own gateway logic, we are forced to use the **[Create Purchase](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-purchase)** method, as opposed to Create Subscription (as **Create Subscription** doesn't accept `gateway_code` as a parameter). **Create Subscription** returns the created subscription - easy!

But **Create Purchase** returns an Invoice Collection. It's possible to tease this apart to find the newly-created `$subscription` object but this hardly seems like the intended process. Is there (hopefully) a cleaner way of going about it?

My method for purchasing is as follows - see code comments.

```
protected static function create_subscription( $user_id, $args ) {

    $result = false;

    $purchase = new Recurly_Purchase();
    $purchase->currency          = $args['currency'];
    $purchase->collection_method = 'automatic';
    $purchase->gateway_code      = $args['gateway_code'];

    $account             = new Recurly_Account( $user_id );
    $account->email      = $args['email'];
    $account->first_name = $args['billing_first_name'];
    $account->last_name  = $args['billing_last_name'];
    $account->vat_number = $args['vat_number'];

    $billing_info           = new Recurly_BillingInfo();
    $billing_info->token_id = $args['recurly_token'];

    $account->billing_info = $billing_info;

    $purchase->account = $account;

    $subscription            = new Recurly_Subscription();
    $subscription->plan_code = $args['plan_code'];

    $purchase->subscriptions = array( $subscription );

    try {
        // "invoice" is the method to transact a Recurly_Purchase.
        $purchase = Recurly_Purchase::invoice( $purchase );
        if( $purchase instanceof Recurly_InvoiceCollection ) {
           // this seems incredibly janky and error-prone
           $result = reset( $purchase->charge_invoice->line_items )->subscription->get();
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $result = $e;
    }
    // I need this to return the $subscription object generated by the purchase
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a subscription, a successful response will include the UUID for that subscription. I am not a PHP developer but it might look something like this:

```
 $subscription = new Recurly_Subscription();
 $subscription->plan_code = $args['plan_code'];
 $subscription->account = $account;
 $subscription->currency = $args['currency'];
 $subscription->create();
 $uuid = isset($subscription->uuid);
 $result = Recurly_Subscription::get($uuid);
 return $result;
```

Also, please note that as of Recurly API version 2.17+ you can now pass `gateway_code` as a body param to [create subscription](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-subscription) *AND* [create purchase](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-purchase) as you initially hoped to do. Here is a link to the [Recurly API Release notes](https://dev.recurly.com/page/api-release-notes), which indicates when the change was made.

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to get the subscription from a `Recurly_InvoiceCollection` - not create a subscription from scratch. I should also note that you still _**cannot**_ pass `gateway_code` to `create_purchase` - as I noted in the question, we can't use `create_subscription` for this reason.

Comment: Ok, no worries. For the record, you *can* pass `gateway_code` to `create_purchase`, which is listed as the penultimate parameter in the same link you posted in your original question. My answer cited `create_subscription`, but I added the link to `create_purchase` for clarity.

Comment: They claimed that was true but I've gotten independent confirmation from the developers that it is still not available. The documentation is wrong.